# How to split defined macros in C++

Tags: c++

is there any way i can split a defined fucntion like macro in c++?

I have defined:

```
#define FF cout<<
#define GG(X) X
#define HH <<endl;
```

could i make something like  :

```
#define FF     cout << GG(
#define GG(X)  X
#define HH     ) << endl;
```

in order to call it like FF "example" HH?
Thank you.

Comment: Those are not functions, they are macros. It is also a very abusive use of macros.

Comment: And no there's no way to "split" it like you want to do.

Comment: ... and why in the world would you want to use macros in such a way?

Comment: I would also firmly recommend against using macros like that, as it tends to obfuscate the code you write, making it harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Macro expansion is a single pass process so no, but why do you need to?  `FF "example" HH` expands to `cout<< "example" <<endl;` in any case - what is the purpose of `GG`?

Comment: It is for a project. I need to emulate a language using defines.. GG() will also do other stuff.

Comment: @konstantinosAR : In that case it is a badly formed question, because all you will get is comments that it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-processor runs in a single pass, so what you are attempting is not directly possible, however for most compilers it is possible to run the pre-processor independently and obtain pre-processed output before compilation, in that case if you were to have:

*toy_language_macros.h:*

```
#if !defined TOY_LANGUAGE_MACROS_INCL
    #define TOY_LANGUAGE_MACROS_INCL
    #define GG(X)  X
    #define FF     cout << GG(
    #define HH     ) << endl;
#endif
```

*toy_language_script.toy*

```
#include "toy_language_macros.h"
FF "example" HH
```

After pre-processing you would have:

```
cout<< GG("example") <<endl;
```

If you then modify this output by re-inserting the header:

```
#include "toy_language_macros.h"
cout<< GG("example") <<endl;
```

Then run *that* through the pre-processor, you will then get:

```
cout<< "example" <<endl;
```

If you were to to write your own "translator" you could automate this *insert-header then pre-process and repeat*. You would have to compare the pre-processor output with the previous pre-processor in order to determine that all nested macros were fully expanded - repeating as many times as necessary.

I can imagine lost of problems occurring with this, but it is the only way I can see of using the pre-processor to translate your "language" to compilable C++.